# How can we show 10 thousand reocrds from MySQL into *Graph in Laravel 5.5 Blade view*?

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-blade

I have 10 thousand records in the **MySQL table**. I have used **indexing** to get a better result and all other techniques that are available in **WWW**. when records were around 3000 then it was taking 3 seconds but after that, my system takes 8 seconds to get data and show in **Graph**. that is too high. I want to reduce this. I am using **Laravel 5.5**.

I am showing the last 12 months revenue of bookings in Graph. here I am getting the booking Id from the `Booking` model and looking at all data from the `BookingDetails` model.

Note that if I am disabling **barryvdh/laravel-debugbar** then it is being loaded in 3seconds.

> My **BookingDetails Table Structure**.

[image]

```
function pastTwelveMonthsTotalRevenue()
{
    $month = false;
    $today = Carbon\Carbon::now();

    $firstDay_this_month = new Carbon\Carbon('first day of this month');
    $start_date_this_month = $firstDay_this_month->startOfDay();
    $todayYear = $start_date_this_month->subYear(1)->startOfDay();
    $lastDay_last_month = new Carbon\Carbon('last day of last month');
    $end_date_last_month = $lastDay_last_month->endOfDay();



   // filtering all booking id with all condition.   
    $bookings = Booking::whereIn('trip_status', [1, 2])
        ->whereIn('trip_status', [1, 2])
        ->where('status', 1)
        ->where('booking_or_quotes', 1)
        ->whereBetween('booking.booking_time', [$todayYear, $end_date_last_month]);

    if ($franchisees) {
        $bookings->where('franchisees_id', $franchisees);
    }
    else
    {
        $bookings->whereHas('franchisees',function ($q){ $q->where('test_franchisee',0); });
    }

    $bookingsId =  $bookings->select('id')->get()->pluck('id');

    // now directly collecting those records that have filtered.
    // to get quickly i am only uisng filtered bookings Id here.

    $query = \App\BookingDetails::select('booking.booking_time',
        'booking.price_without_vat', 'booking.custom_price','booking_details.*',
        DB::raw("DATE_FORMAT(booking_time,'%Y%m')  as dt"))
        ->join('booking', 'booking.id', '=', 'booking_details.booking_id')
        ->whereIn( 'booking_id' , $bookingsId )
        ->whereBetween('booking.booking_time', [$todayYear, $end_date_last_month])
        ->orderBy(DB::raw("dt"));

    $query->with("booking:id,booking_time,price_without_vat,custom_price");
    $bookingModels = $query->get();

    $dataChart = array();
    $chartLabels = array();
    $color = array();
    $data = array();

    if (collect($bookingModels)->count()) {
        // Group all record on Y-M date order.
        $bookingModelCls = collect($bookingModels)->groupBy(DB::raw("dt"));

        foreach ($bookingModelCls as $key => $models) {

            $month = substr($key, 4, 2);

            $total_ern = $total_exp = 0;

            if (collect($models)->count()) {

                $month = $month * 1;

                $driverRevenue =  graphDriverTotalRevenue($models);
                $companionRevenue = graphCompanionTotalRevenue($models);
                $profit =  $driverRevenue + $companionRevenue ;
                $data[] = round($profit, 2);
                $color[] = getColor($key);
                $chartLabels[] = getMonthsName($month) . "'" . substr($models[0]['dt'], 2, 2);
            }
        }
    }


    $dataChart[] = array(
        'label' => false,
        'fill' => false,
        'backgroundColor' => $color,
        'borderColor' => $color,
        'data' => $data
    );

    return array(
        'labels' => $chartLabels,
        'data' => $dataChart
    );

}
```

Here in this method, I am using **Inner-Join**. using that I can get all data that is coming from the **BookingDetails** Table. but this code was written by a different user and due to lack of time, I did not change the whole code. so i used `->with("bookingDetails")` to get data from Booking Details Tables.

So Data is coming around 4 to 6 seconds but when it is being loaded into Chat(Graph). It is taking 10 to 20 seconds or sometimes it is crashing the browser.

I checked the comment. so I have added answers to the comments.  First, there is no **N+1** problem. all query is unique. as I am thinking it is being problem inside of **Blade view**. because when I show only JSON data then it is loading in 1 or 2 seconds or sometimes 3 seconds. but yes 3 sec is also very long.. but mostly time it becomes loaded in 10 seconds when data passed into view and represent the **Graph**.

[image]

Can anyone suggest to me any other optimized eloquent solution for this problem?

Comment: Question is valid. i am also facing such issue.  for this i have created new table in which i am storing all graph  data and when any data modify or delete i updates that table. it is not good but helping me.

Comment: If there are only 3000 records, it should not take 3 to 7 seconds that long. Looks like a `N+1` problem.

Comment: Also, is this a problem on the mysql side or is this a rendering problem in the web browser?

Comment: Unfortunately you first have to identify which part of your code is slow. The question is unclear otherwise.

Comment: 3K dots (or 10K) in a graph seems excessive.  And does the data before the current month (or even day) ever change?

Comment: @shadow i think this is being from rendering time. because when only show response then it comes sometime in 1sec ...

Comment: @ikhvjs i have checked there is no **N+1** problem. All query is Unique. i checked in **laravel Query Debugger**.

Comment: @RickJames it is the last 12 months data. everyday data updates and creates. so it always changes.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this isn't related to PHP or Laravel, there is no table definition or `my.cnf`.

Comment: @MartinZeitler how you can say this there is no table definition and laravel relation. did you ready full description? how can you vote for close it?

Comment: Could you show us your table definition and the SQL you try to run? Maybe you should check the execution plan of the SQL to see if there is any redundant join? I still think it is the SQL issue rather than the data if the data size is small.

Comment: @ikhvjs such a small data size is the one that suggests this is not an sql issue. 10k row is not a big deal for mysql on a modern computer. However, rendering 10k objects in browser is a bigger task and we have no clue how that's done.

Comment: @AnkitSharma if you think this is a rendering issue, then you need to change your question to focus on the rendering piece not on the database one. You may even want to delete this question and re-ask it.

Comment: @Shadow, it is a big deal. 10k with necessary join with another 10k data set. It would be a big data set then. 10k x 10k

Comment: @ikhvjs you would only get a 10kx10k dataset as a result of a join if a join was a cartesian one. There is a proper join condition in the query, so it is not a cartesian one.

Comment: @Shadow, if you say so, but that's why I am asking for the Table structure and SQL to be sure.

Comment: @ikhvjs you can see the join condition in the laravel code already.

Comment: To resolve many of the comments, please show us the _generated_ SQL statement that fetches the data for Graph.

Comment: With a suitable index, it would be 10K + 10K, not 10K x 10K.  (Hence, we need to see the table definitions.)  Note:  I am focusing on the "suitable index" -- a `JOIN` can be terribly slow or it can be quite fast, _depending on the indexing_.

Comment: Another way to move this discussion along is to time the fetching of the data that will be sent to Graph.  cf php's `microtime(true)`.

Comment: @Shadow  i have updated my Question and description and added Table definition. please check, when i removed  **barryvdh/laravel-debugbar** then it is being loading soon.

Comment: @RickJames can you help me to write fast and optimistic code for fetch data. i have added table defination.

Answer (score 0):

The technique is to build and maintain another table that is a "summary" of the data.  It would, for example, hold daily subtotals.  Then the graph could be built from it.  About 400 rows to scan is a lot faster than 3K (or 10K), and it should give all data needed for the graph your presented (or even graphs with more resolution.)

More:  [*Summary Tables*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/summarytables)

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. i will check this.

Comment: yes. little bit i am doing same thing.

Comment: II'm sorry, but 10k rows is peanuts for mysql running on a modern computer, even if there is no index. The OP also confirmed in a comment later on that the query itself runs quickly, it is the rendering that takes a lot of time. No need to maintain a summary table, just generate the summary on the fly with a query and render its results.